# How can I create a calculation with a Snowflake SQL statement from 2 different tables with no join criteria?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a calendar table where I wrote this calculation out to obtain the DAILY_RATIO value which is needed in my main calculation:

```
select 
  (DATE_PART(DAY, CURRENT_DATE()) - 1) / (MAX(BUSINESS_DAY_COUNT)) as DAILY_RATIO 
from reporting_db.public.dim_calendar 
where year = DATE_PART(YEAR, CURRENT_DATE()) 
  and MONTH_NUMBER = DATE_PART(MONTH, CURRENT_DATE());
```

And for reference, the ratio for today is 0.086957

I have also written out this query for calculating totals from our FORECAST table (this one is for FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES_$):

```
select 
  FORECAST_DATE, 
  SUM(FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES_$) 
from REPORTING_DB.PUBLIC.FORECAST 
group by 1
having FORECAST_DATE = CURRENT_DATE() - (DATE_PART(DAY, CURRENT_DATE())-1);
```

| FORECASTE_DATE | SUM(FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES_$) |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-08-01 | 59562223.1400 |

What I'm trying to accomplish is a sql output of something along the lines of this:

|  | August Total | Daty 2 Ratio | Pro-rated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES_$ | 59,562,223.14 | 0.08696 | 5,179,530.92 |
| FORECAST_TOTAL_MARGIN_$ | 12,577,085.62 | 0.08696 | 1,09,703.37 |
| FORECAST_EXTEND_NET_WGHT_LB | 109,974,804.99 | 0.08696 | 9,563,409.04 |
| FORECAST_TOTAL_COST_$ | 46,985,137.52 | 0.08696 | 4,085,827.56 |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
| Total Margin / Total Sales |  |  | 0.211158767 |

But from a sql statement so that the business user can just run this query daily to verify totals.

I can't figure out how to marry these two tables together to achieve this output.

Any SQL gurus help much appreciated!

So far I have tried the above sql statements but need to pair them together into one for an output desired by the table above.

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text. Show sample source data, the result you are trying to achieve and the SQL you’ve managed to write so far

Comment: if I'm understanding this right, this is primarily a question of formatting the result, yes? hopefully my answer below can help with that.
If you are having other issues on join conditions, it would be helpful to have a more complete simple sample that is giving you wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

Since all your queries are returning single values, you could just put them into variables and then query those to create a result set.

```
set daily_ratio = (
    select (DATE_PART(DAY, CURRENT_DATE()) - 1) / (MAX(BUSINESS_DAY_COUNT)) as DAILY_RATIO 
    from reporting_db.public.dim_calendar 
    where year = DATE_PART(YEAR, CURRENT_DATE()) and MONTH_NUMBER = DATE_PART(MONTH, CURRENT_DATE());
);

set forecast = (
    select SUM(FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES_$) from REPORTING_DB.PUBLIC.FORECAST group by FORECAST_DATE
    having FORECAST_DATE = CURRENT_DATE() - (DATE_PART(DAY, CURRENT_DATE())-1);
);

SELECT $daily_ratio, $forecast
--UNION ALL 
--  SELECT $daily_ratio, $forecast_margin -- etc.
```

Depending on how you might want to extend this, you could

- Create these as variables in [sql scripting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index) so that you can run it all in one execution
- Build these queries in CTEs or temporary tables so that you can include multiple columns/rows for a given query more easily
- join these queries on a date column so that you can include multiple dates in a single output.

Answer (score 0):

So if we recreate some fake input data:

```
with dim_calendar(year, month_number, business_day_count) as (
    select year(column1),
        month(column1),
        column2
    from values
    ('2023-08-01'::date, 1),
    ('2023-08-02'::date, 2),
    ('2023-08-03'::date, 3),
    /* ... */
    ('2023-08-28'::date, 21),
    ('2023-08-29'::date, 22),
    ('2023-08-30'::date, 23)    
)
select 
  (DATE_PART(DAY, CURRENT_DATE()) - 1) / (MAX(BUSINESS_DAY_COUNT)) as DAILY_RATIO 
from dim_calendar 
where year = DATE_PART(YEAR, CURRENT_DATE()) 
  and MONTH_NUMBER = DATE_PART(MONTH, CURRENT_DATE());
```

same result:

[image]

```
with FORECAST(FORECAST_DATE, FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES) as (
    select * from values
    ('2023-08-01', 59562221.1400::number(28,4)),
    ('2023-08-01', 2::number(28,4))
)
select 
  FORECAST_DATE, 
  SUM(FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES) 
from FORECAST 
group by 1
having FORECAST_DATE = CURRENT_DATE() - (DATE_PART(DAY, CURRENT_DATE())-1);
```

more sameness:

[image]

So now to blend these just use a CROSS JOIN which is a every row from A with every row from B, but given you only have one row each, you get the result you want:

```
with dim_calendar(year, month_number, business_day_count) as (
    select year(column1),
        month(column1),
        column2
    from values
    ('2023-08-01'::date, 1),
    ('2023-08-02'::date, 2),
    ('2023-08-03'::date, 3),
    /* ... */
    ('2023-08-28'::date, 21),
    ('2023-08-29'::date, 22),
    ('2023-08-30'::date, 23)    
), FORECAST(FORECAST_DATE, FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES) as (
    select * 
    from values
    ('2023-08-01', 59562221.1400::number(28,4)),
    ('2023-08-01', 2::number(28,4))
), today_ratio as (
    select 
      round((DATE_PART(DAY, CURRENT_DATE()) - 1) / (MAX(BUSINESS_DAY_COUNT)),5) as DAILY_RATIO 
    from dim_calendar 
    where year = DATE_PART(YEAR, CURRENT_DATE()) 
      and MONTH_NUMBER = DATE_PART(MONTH, CURRENT_DATE())
), todays_forecasts as (
    select 
      FORECAST_DATE, 
      SUM(FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES) as FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES
    from FORECAST 
    group by 1
    having FORECAST_DATE = CURRENT_DATE() - (DATE_PART(DAY, CURRENT_DATE())-1)
)
select
    'FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES' as "_"
    ,FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES as "August Total"
    ,r.DAILY_RATIO as "Daty 2 Ratio"
    ,round(FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES * r.DAILY_RATIO, 2) as "Pro-rated"
from today_ratio as r
cross join todays_forecasts as f
;
```

[image]

BUT you also show many values that are summed, and to be honest, that looks like a PIVOT

### SQL improvements:

so there are many things to clean-up in your SQL

`DATE_PART(YEAR, CURRENT_DATE())` can be `YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())` or if you are happy with upper case, `YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)`, which goes the same for `(DATE_PART(DAY, CURRENT_DATE())` -> `DAY(CURRENT_DATE)` and `(DATE_PART(MONTH, CURRENT_DATE())` -> `MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)`

for the Forecast SQL, you should change the HAVING to a WHERE, because you are summarizing a whole table, and then throwing away results, and the pruned results, cannot have an impact on the SUM as they are the same value being compared. Also `CURRENT_DATE() - (DAY(CURRENT_DATE)-1)` is a date truncation to the beginning of the month of which `date_trunc(month, CURRENT_DATE)` expresses cleaner:

```
    select 
      FORECAST_DATE, 
      SUM(FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES) as FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES
    from FORECAST 
    group by 1
    having FORECAST_DATE = CURRENT_DATE() - (DAY(CURRENT_DATE)-1)
```

becomes:

```
    select 
      FORECAST_DATE, 
      SUM(FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES) as FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES
    from FORECAST 
    where FORECAST_DATE = date_trunc(month, CURRENT_DATE)
    group by 1
```

so it can be a little cleaner written as :

```
with dim_calendar(year, month_number, business_day_count) as (
    select year(column1),
        month(column1),
        column2
    from values
    ('2023-08-01'::date, 1),
    ('2023-08-02'::date, 2),
    ('2023-08-03'::date, 3),
    /* ... */
    ('2023-08-28'::date, 21),
    ('2023-08-29'::date, 22),
    ('2023-08-30'::date, 23)    
), FORECAST(FORECAST_DATE, FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES) as (
    select * 
    from values
    ('2023-08-01', 59562221.1400::number(28,4)),
    ('2023-08-01', 2::number(28,4))
), today_ratio as (
    select 
      round((DAY(CURRENT_DATE) - 1) / (MAX(BUSINESS_DAY_COUNT)),5) as DAILY_RATIO 
    from dim_calendar 
    where year = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) 
      and MONTH_NUMBER = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
), todays_forecasts as (
    select 
      FORECAST_DATE, 
      SUM(FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES) as FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES
    from FORECAST 
    where FORECAST_DATE = date_trunc(month, CURRENT_DATE)
    group by 1
) 
select
    'FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES' as "_"
    ,FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES as "August Total"
    ,r.DAILY_RATIO as "Daty 2 Ratio"
    ,round(FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES * r.DAILY_RATIO, 2) as "Pro-rated"
from today_ratio as r
cross join todays_forecasts as f
;
```

### Yes, but that awesome table:

Well if you pivot your data, or just UNION ALL it together:

```
), pivoted_data("_", "August Total") as (
    select     
        'FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES' as "_"
        ,f.FORECAST_TOTAL_SALES as "August Total"
    from todays_forecasts as f

    union all

    select 'FORECAST_TOTAL_MARGIN', 12577085.62

    union all 

    select 'FORECAST_EXTEND_NET_WGHT_LB', 109974804.99
    
    union all 

    select 'FORECAST_TOTAL_COST', 46985137.52   
)
```

you can cross join that:

```
select
    p."_"
    ,p."August Total"
    ,r.DAILY_RATIO as "Daty 2 Ratio"
    ,round(p."August Total" * r.DAILY_RATIO, 2) as "Pro-rated"
from today_ratio as r
cross join pivoted_data as p
```

[image]